# Python Try not executed after Except?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, valueerror, except

I am stuck on the python code displayed below my question.

This code is part of a supervised neural network project.
`encoder.inverse_transform(x)` yields a ValueError when an unknown label is encountered.

What I expect is: the code returns a result for every x and when x is not in `encoder.classes_` the result for that x will be `'Onbekend'`.

What it does is: when Output contains one unknown label the code results in a single 'Onbekend' irrespective of the number of x.
It seems like the try function is not executed for every x in Output when.

Does anyone know what I am missing here?

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
import bisect

# Dataframe creation
data = {'Text': ['Koffie', 'Auto onderdelen','Brandstof', 'Zeilen', 'Studie', 
'Cadeau', 'Telefoon'], 'Labels': ['Leven', 'Auto', 'Auto', 'Leven', 'Studie', 
'Leven', 'Telefonie']}
trainDF = pd.DataFrame(data=data,
                       dtype = str)

#split the dataset into training and validation datasets
train_x, valid_x, train_y, valid_y = 
model_selection.train_test_split(trainDF['Text'], trainDF['Labels'])

# label encode the target variable
encoder = LabelEncoder()
train_y = encoder.fit_transform(train_y)
valid_y = encoder.fit_transform(valid_y)

# Create a count vectorizer object
count_vect = CountVectorizer(analyzer = 'word', token_pattern='\w{1,}')
count_vect.fit(trainDF['Text'])

# Transform the training and validation data using count vectorizer object
xtrain_count = count_vect.transform(train_x)
xvalid_count = count_vect.transform(valid_x)

classifier = LogisticRegression()
classifier.fit(xtrain_count, train_y)

# Modelling
xinput_count = count_vect.transform(trainDF['Text'])
Output = classifier.predict(xinput_count)

for x in Output:
    b = b + 1
    try:
        R = encoder.inverse_transform(Output)
    except ValueError:
        R = 'Onbekend'

encoder_classes = encoder.classes_.tolist()
bisect.insort_left(encoder_classes, 'Onbekend')
encoder.classes_ = encoder_classes

print(R)
```

Comment: Use `except Exception as e:` and then `print(e)` to ensure your checking for the right thing.

Comment: @PatrickArtner, the continue was part of the checks to see if except stopped the for loop. This is not the case so I removed continue.

Comment: Thanks for editing, removed the closevote and upv. Please follow @Rolf advice.

Comment: @RolfSaxony, thanks for your suggestion. I tried it but it did not resolve my issue. If one unknown label is present, irrespective of known labels, the code still returns a single value 'onbekend'.

Answer (score 0):

The code should be:

```
for x in Output:
    try:
        x = encoder.inverse_transform(x)
    except ValueError:
        x = 'Onbekend'
    print(x)
```

Because `print(x)` was not nested inside the for loop it would return the last value of x and not the complete array.

The misleading part was the fact that `R = encoder.inverse_transform(Output)` was using the complete Output array, `print(R)` would return the complete array, given that `Output` contained only known labels, making it look like the code was correct.